# Facet wrap labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-wrap

I produced the graph ...

[image]

... using this code:

```
  ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Elevation , y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~variable, nrow = 3 ) +
  labs(x = c("Elevation" , "Rivers", "NDVI"), y = NULL, color = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside", strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))+ 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))
```

How I can produce the labels show in the attached image, X are the labels desire to remove. I want to show "Elevation, NDVI and Rivers " on the x axis but only "Elevation is appearing, while I want to show single label for "Ibex, Snow Leopard and Cooccurrence" on right hand side.

similar to one produce by Rota et al 2016[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzq3S.png)

Comment: Have you checked `facet_grid()` function?

Comment: Yes, I produced the graph using this code:                                                                                             ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Elevation , y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~variable,  nrow = 3 ) +
  labs(x = c("Elevation" , "Rivers", "NDVI"), y = NULL, color = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal working code and a snippet of your data (best shared using `dput()`) or some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Comment: @HussainAli You’re using `facet_wrap()`, but @Dan suggested `facet_grid()`. For instance if `ENR` is a variable with values for Elevation v. NDVI v. Rivers and `ISC` has values for Ibex v. Snow Leopard v. Cooccurrence, you would do `facet_grid(ISC ~ ENR)`.